# Unevenly space in D3 axis using rangePoints

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 (v3) to build a plot with two axis. One of them it isn't working correctly when I add two or more objects. My piece of code is:

```
    //Set upperLevelyScale
var previousValues = 0;
var upperLevelyScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(Object.keys(valuesY_numbers).sort())
    .rangePoints((function(){
        var values = Object.values(valuesY_numbers).map(function(x){
            previousValues += (x * itemSize);
            return previousValues});
        values.unshift(0);
        return values;
    })());
```

when domain is ["MyValue1"] and rangePoints is [0, 170], the tick of the axis shows perfectly at the middle of the axis. But if domain is ["MyValue1", "MyValue2"] and rangePoints is [0,170,320] the ticks are not really covering their part but other.

What I'm trying to set up is just: MyValue1 is from 0 to 170, MyValue2 is from 170 to 320, etc. I have tried with '.range' also but still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to pass just two values to `rangePoints`, as an array: `[min, max]`.

Comment: So if I want a custom scale like the example (MyValue1 is from 0 to 170, MyValue2 is from 170 to 320, etc) what should I use? because I have seen '.range' working with linear scales, but not working with my ordinal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have uneven bands. You'll have to create your own scale.